# Getting codec error when parsing json with Django REST

Tags: python, json, django, codec

I'm using Django REST Framework and I'm getting error when parsing json code. When I send json code that conatin special character for example :

```
# Client
self.info = json.dumps(u'{"culture": "Blé"}', ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf-8")
resp = self.client.post(
        '/Test/', self.info,
        content_type='application/json;  charset=utf-8',
         )

# Server 
stream = StringIO(request.DATA)
data = parsers.JSONParser().parse(stream)
```

I get this error returned :

> {"detail": "JSON parse error - 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)"}

What's the problem and how to fix it?

ps: I have looked to questions similar to my case but I didn't found an answer.

Comment: For the googlers, this is solved by using `format='json'` and getting rid of `json.dumps` and passing the `dict` directly. No need to `content_type` argument. Or, probably solved by doing the posted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245213/908336) and removing `content_type='application/json'`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `json.dumps` on a string instead of a dict, which results in double escaping.

You'd want `self.info` to be a Unicode string with your payload encoded as utf-8 json, so you can say:

```
self.info = json.dumps({"culture": u"Blé"})
# or just use a string in the first place
self.info = u'{"culture": "Blé"}'
```

Comment: When I do that I got this error : `JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: I don't have traceback. Django REST catch the exception and return the error message. I don't know what to do to get the traceback